# Monitor keypress/keystroke using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, keypress

I am developing a small desktop utility in which I need to summon my utility when a particular set of keys are pressed (Alt+c).

I tried the `keypress` module. But it only listens to the keypresses made at the place where my script is running (i.e. while my control has focus).

I want to listen to all the keypresses. How can this be implemented?

PS: Consider my utility somewhat like Gnome-DO where by pressing Win+Space you summon the application.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the keyboard events globally, you must access the system event file associated to the keyboard.

To identify the keyboard event file, under the path

```
/dev/input/
```

there is a list of eventX files, each one associated to a different input device. By executing

```
sudo evtest /dev/input/eventX
```

and later pushing keyboard keys, you can identify which is the event file associated to it.
Through this file you will have the raw keyboard event data, you will have to parse it.
There are [documentation](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/input.h?v=2.6.11.8) to process this raw data.

Also, there are projects which reads from the keyboard event file:

https://github.com/Bornholm/node-keyboard

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I'll check this out and reply asap. See if it serves my purpose.